Homotopy between bounded linear operators on Banach spaces
In my course of Functional Analysis, talking about continuity method and index of Frendholm operators we construct homotopy between operators. However i encountered some difficulties to connecting this construction with the standard definition of homotopy.
Notation:
def(1)[STD homotopy definition] Let $X, Y$ be topological spaces, let $I\subset \mathbb{R}$ be the closed unit interval,  let be $f, g \in C(X, Y)$; we call homotopy from f to g a map $$H:I \times X \to Y \text{, such that:}$$

$H \in C(I \times X, Y)$, where $I \times X$ is endowed with product topology
$H(0, x) = f(x),  \, \forall x \in X$
$H(1, x) = g(x),  \, \forall x \in X$

On my course we say:
Let $X, Y$ be Banach spaces, let $\mathcal{L}(X, Y)$ be the bounded linear map spaces endowed with operator-norm, let be $A \in C(I, \mathcal{L}(X, Y))$, then $A$ 'define' an homotopy from $f=A_0$ and $g=A_1$
My question:

It is possible to define $H$ such that $H(t, x) = A_t(x)$ and prove that H is an homotopy from $A_0$ and $A_1$ iff $A \in C(I, \mathcal{L}(X, Y))$

If the answer is yes, with what generality? i.e can $X, Y$ not be metrizable? Is the linear structure crucial? i.e can we take $X, Y$ not linear space and replace $\mathcal{L}(X, Y)$ with $C(X, Y)$ endowed with some topology?


My suggestions:
The implication $\Longleftarrow$ seem to me reasonable. Instead the other implication i think it is false. Because all of this objects lives in metric spaces, since the continuity of H, $\forall \epsilon, \, \exists \delta = \delta(\epsilon, t_0, \color{red}{x})$ such that if $|t-t_0| \leq \delta$ then $\|H(t, x) - H(t_0, x) \|_Y \leq \epsilon$.
The $x$-dependence of $\delta$ it seems to me problematic because $A \in C(I, \mathcal{L}(X, Y))$ implies that $\forall \epsilon, \, \exists \delta = \delta(\epsilon, t_0)$ such that if $|t-t_0| \leq \delta$ then $\|A_t - A_{t_0} \| \leq \epsilon$. So in this second case we have a small distance in term of operator norm that is more strictly then a small pointwise distance of the operator.
